# wipe off effect in iphone game

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iphone game, which needs to wipe off the brain goo splashed on the screen by fingers.

When I wipe the screen with my finger, it works well on simulater, but when I test it on my device, the track on the screen is totally different from the track of my finger.

It seems that they are in opposite direction.

For example, If I wipe the the upper half of the screen, the track I got is on the bottom half of the screen.

Anybody can help me? Does CCRenderTexture performs different on Simulater and real device?

Comment: I can't help because I have not enough skills of telepathy :)

Comment: There must be someone knows this skill, please help me1

Comment: Possibly the orientation of the iPhone is flipped i.e. you have to mirror the coordinates?

Comment: Hey, can anybody tell me names of iphone games that have the similar effect?